# Failed to import bridging header in parent Project

Tags: swift, xcode, bridging-header

I have a project in Xcode that has one or more child projects. The child projects are frameworks, which include some static libs and have header search paths specified.

Now when I want to compile the parent project, it complains that it can't find the imports from the subprojects' bridging header.

Obviously it's not going to find it, because the paths are only specified for the subproject, which is what I want.

Why does the parent project even look at my subprojects bridging header? It is not its concern. How do I disable this?

Comment: Remove it manually from the parent project build settings: `SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER`

Comment: It's not in the parent projects build settings

Comment: Having the same issue, any solutions ?